# How to get lambda functions list in command prompt?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda

I have two lambda functions in my AWS account need to use those functions in my localhost. First tried to get list of functions in command prompt. Configuration done with my account secret key and access key using following command.

```
aws configure
```

After configuration done i have run the command to get list of lambda functions using following command

```
aws lambda list-functions
```

But its return empty, but i have two lambda functions.

```
{
    "Functions": []
}
```

what would be the right solution?

Comment: Wrong `AWS_REGION`!? Wrong AWS account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credentails of the user that you use configure the AWS-CLI should have the persmission to list-functions in the current region.

Things you should check:

1. Check what level of persmission you had configured for the user
2. Check if your user and functions lies in the same region

Comment: I have provided AdministratorAccess for the user and region i have used us-east-1. I am used from India.

Comment: yes i have changed the region which is mentioned in aws lambda function while configuration. its working

Comment: @manikandan that is the first lesson you need to learn: when you do not see something that you expect to be there: **check the region**, always check and double check the region, no matter how experienced you are :D

Comment: It doesn not matter from which part of the world you're using it.
You need to make sure the user configuration was correct. 
check the "default region name" in ~/.aws/config